# Preserve whitespace between tags

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am not sure what is wrong in below grammar, would appreciate any kind of help. I have simplified the query for answer purpose, but trying to get search keyword with whitespace intact, in return I do get the string back, but all whitespace are removed. For example, if i pass my search query as Best Buy then I get BestBuy in return.

Below is the simplified grammar, i want to extract exact words/phrase that includes whitespace,comma etc.  specified in keyword block

## Search Syntax

KEYWORD = [ Best Buy ] //want to maintain whitespace between [ and ]

```
identlit : RESKEYWORD OPERATOR keywordidentifier  ;  
keywordidentifier : '[' (~']') * ']';
RESKEYWORD: K E Y W O R D;
OPERATOR: [=] ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

## Tried other version of grammar but same issue

```
identlit : RESKEYWORD OPERATOR '[' keywordidentifier  ']';
keywordidentifier : KEYWORDID*;         
KEYWORDID : [a-zA-Z0-9]+ ;      // match identifiers
RESKEYWORD: K E Y W O R D;
OPERATOR: [=] ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really not that hard to get everything out. You can use your grammar to parse the input. Whitespaces are skipped as per your WS lexer rule. However, in order to reconstruct your original input you can use the generated tokens which contain an index into the input token stream. Use them to seek your input stream to the right position and then iterate over all following tokens (regardless of the channel) until you find the final token (e.g. '[' and ']'). That way you get exactly what was fed in.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what exactly you are asking for but upto i understood while writing your regex use '\s' in regex. \s is for white space eg: [a-za-Z0-9\s]

Comment: Thanks Pritam for your response. I did try using the regex approach but that doesn't solve my problem, issue is space gets automatically trimmed during parsing, for example when I pass this input "Pritam Narkhede" during parsing I get "PritamNarkhede" so somehow ANTLR parser skips whitespace even though in my rule identifier I have specifically mentioned to capture WS. Hope this clarifies. Thanks again for your help.